# How can I convert a string to date (php)?

Tags: php

I would like to convert `30.10.2014 15\:25\:24` to `30/Oct/2014 15:25:24`. I tried it like this...

```
$s = '30.10.2014 15\:25\:24';
$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date);
```

... but my result is 01.Jan.1970 01:00:00

Comment: $Date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($Date));

Answer (score 0):

Its because strtotime returned FALSE , code shown below

```
$s = '30.10.2014 15\:25\:24';  //invalid format
$date = strtotime($s);
if($date===FALSE)  //if strtotime failed
{
    echo "strtotime failed";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I convert `30.10.2014 15\:25\:24` to `30/Oct/2014 15:25:24`?

Comment: $s = str_replace("\\","/","30.10.2014 15\:25\:24");

Comment: dont forget to check this answer as accepted if ur satisfied :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried `$s = str_replace("\\","/","30.10.2014 15\:25\:24")`  as you said, but I still get the result `strtotime failed`

Comment: if you remove / and \ this from time, you will get correct result.... try this --->

 $s = '30.10.2014 15:25:24';
$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date);

Comment: I finaly found the problem. I need to write `$s = str_replace("\\","","30.10.2014 15\:25\:24");` and not  `$s = str_replace("\\","/","30.10.2014 15\:25\:24");`